# Compiling custom angular material theme SASS with Gulp and Visual Studio and Webpack

Tags: angular, visual-studio, sass, gulp

I have followed the following link to add SASS to my asp.net core SPA project.

[Adding SASS to Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44317227/3545438)

I have them added the following file;

```
 /Content/sass/angular-material.sass
```

which is as follows;

```
//@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
// Plus imports for other components in your app.

// Include the common styles for Angular Material. We include this here so that you only
// have to load a single css file for Angular Material in your app.
// Be sure that you only ever include this mixin once!
@include mat-core();

// Define the palettes for your theme using the Material Design palettes available in palette.scss
// (imported above). For each palette, you can optionally specify a default, lighter, and darker
// hue. Available color palettes: https://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html
$candy-app-primary: mat-palette($mat-indigo);
$candy-app-accent: mat-palette($mat-pink, A200, A100, A400);

// The warn palette is optional (defaults to red).
$candy-app-warn: mat-palette($mat-red);

// Create the theme object (a Sass map containing all of the palettes).
$candy-app-theme: mat-light-theme($candy-app-primary, $candy-app-accent, $candy-app-warn);

// Include theme styles for core and each component used in your app.
// Alternatively, you can import and @include the theme mixins for each component
// that you are using.
@include angular-material-theme($candy-app-theme);
```

However I get the error;

```
undeclared mixin on mat-core();
```

and when i run the Gulp in task runner I get the error;

> Error: File to import not found or unreadable: ~@angular/material/theming.

No from googling around it look like I can specify the the node_modules as an include path, as per this stack question;

[stackoverflow sass question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44317227/3545438)

However as I am running webapck (and still fairly new to this). I dont have an angular-cli.json file present.

Can anyone help here? I dont really want to be adding relative file paths (i.e. ../../../node_modules/etc).

```
  [1]: https://brettthewhitt.com/2017/07/28/stupid-easy-instructions-to-implement-sass-into-your-visual-studio-project/
```